# E with accent doesn't show correctly

Tags: html, character-encoding

On my page, the text in the top middle (« Ce site Internet. ») contains E with accents which on my computer appear as question marks.

This is despite the fact that I have meta charset="UTF-8" in my head tag and the PHP file containing the text appears as UTF-8 when opened with Notepad++.

What's going on then?

Comment: is your server set to give the `utf-8` header?

Comment: Please check the file encoding in notepad++ only and set it to "Encode in UTF-8". I had changed the encoding to "UTF-8" in eclipse and still it did not show me special characters (like é). So I went ahead and checked the encoding of that file in notepad++ and it showed me that encoding was UTF-8 **WITHOUT BOM** . So I changed it to just UTF-8 and replaced file in eclipse and it worked.

If you do in that way, you need not even set 

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 24):

The browser displays these when it can’t make sense of the numbers it is reading.
UTF-8 is self-synchronzising. Unlike other multi-byte character encodings, you always know where you are with UTF-8. If you see a number 192-247, you know you are at the beginning of a multi-byte sequence. If you see 128-191 you know you are in the middle of one. There’s no danger of missing the first number and garbling the rest of the text.
This means that in UTF-8, the sequence 191 followed by 224 will never occur naturally, so the browser doesn’t know what to do with it and displays �� instead.

Use the following in your head tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/

Comment: i used these tags but it didn't sorted italian letters like `e or `a

Comment: Though this helps for plain HTML files, if you have a JSP, try this: ```<%@ page  contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>```

Answer (score 4):

The page is not actually encoded in UTF-8, it is encoded in Latin1. You need to *actually* save the source code files in UTF-8 or otherwise make sure they are output encoded in UTF-8. Currently you have a rift between what the site claims to be encoded in and what it is actually encoded in.

Answer (score 2):

Although you are announcing the content as UTF-8 in the meta and the HTTP headers, it is not UTF-8 that is being sent. You might need to check your PHP settings that it is actually outputting content in the correct encoding. http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the ASCII/HTML codes for the accented characters? If not, [here's a list of them](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/index.php). Search for 'E acute' and you should fine the code for that character (it's `&Eacute;` I think).
At first I thought it was the font-family you were using but I don't think it is because I disabled all styles in my browser and they still appeared as question marks.

More HTML character entities can be found at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Thank Tom, I know this answer seems to be little uneasy to write those codes but this works perfectly. some above answers didn't worked for me but this is type of answer that works everywhere