# Why does email show accented characters as question marks?

Tags: php, mysql, email, collation

If I have the following string in my MySQL database (FYI, Collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci):

```
Bebé Elosúa Sierra
```

It displays fine on my site if I echo it back using htmlentities, but if I send an email via AmazonSES, it shows up (at least in Gmail) like this.

It shows in the body of the email as:

```
Beb? Elos?a Sierra
```

And more oddly, it shows in the subject of the email as:

```
Beb???????????? Elos????????????a Sierra
```

Is there anyway to prevent this, or is it something on Google/Gmail's end that I have no control over?

Comment: The font doesn't have those characters?

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952784/e-with-accent-doesnt-show-correctly

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored