# Handlebars doesn't apply font to each letter inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, handlebars.js

I have a problem where handlebars doesn't apply the font on to each letter which is inside a loop when not in index page. Special letters such as ąčęėįšųū are being rendered with the default font. But it does work on index page.
Below is the index page where everything works correctly:

hbs:

```
{{# each favorites }}
  <div class="row" >
    {{# each this }} 
    <div class="col-sm" >
      <div class="img-thumbnail-thumbnail" alt="text-center" >
   <div class="thumbnail" >
      <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" class="img-fluid-favoriteImage" alt="Responsive image">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1 class = "title">{{this.title}}</h1>
        <div class="price">{{this.price}}€</div>
        <a href="/add-to-cart/{{this._id}}" class="button buttontxt" role="button">užsakyti</a>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
  {{/each}}
```

CSS for font part

```
.title {
text-align: center;
font: normal normal normal 600 14px/20px Montserrat;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #434343;
opacity: 1;
}
```

This is the hbs file which doesn't work correctly:

```
{{# each products }}
<form action = "/add-to-cart2/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "myForm">
<div class="row form-group products">
    {{# each this }} 
 
      <div class = "col">
        <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" class="img-fluid photo" alt="Responsive image" width="200" height="121">
         <h1 class = "title">{{this.title}}</h1>
        <input  type="number" name="Quantity" placeholder="vnt" class="float-right quantity" min="1" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Negalite užsisakyti neigiamo prekių skaičiaus')">
      </div>
      
       
    {{/each}}
</div> 
  {{/each}}
```

CSS which gets applied correctly but not on each letter:

```
.title {
text-align: center;
font: normal normal normal 600 14px/20px Montserrat;
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #434343;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Below is a screenshot which illustrates the result, where not every letter is being "transformed" letter "ė" "š" is incorrect, however what is interesting is that the last item has the letter "ė":
[image]

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: It's important to understand that Handlebars doesn't render fonts - it simply produces strings with some data values substituted for variables. The rendering of styles and fonts is done by the browser and I would guess that the font you are using does not support those special characters.

Comment: It does, as the index page is showing everything correctly. However I am not using handlebars loop there. I am just typing the text in.

Comment: Then I suspect the issue has to do with character-encoding. Maybe this question will be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12952784/3397771